# Не получается удалить повторы из списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Мне нужно удалить повторы названий процессов в списке который я получаю через `os.popen("wmic process get name").read().split()`, я сонный и может просто не вижу чего то элементарного?

```
process_list = os.popen("wmic process get name").read().split()

current_id = 0
for current_process in process_list:
    try:
        current_id += 1
        print(current_process)
        if current_process == process_list[current_id]:
            print("Oops!")
            process_list.remove(current_process)

    except IndexError:
        pass

print(process_list)
```

Пытался удаление через индекс сначала, потом сделал этот. Эффект был должен был одинаковым - все повторы удались и оставили только один результат, но показали одинаковый - только с повторами)

Comment: Простое `process_list = list(set(process_list))` не вариант?

Comment: @andreymal, это хороший вариант, но вдруг нужно сохранить последовательность? Тогда нужен collections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не стоит при итерации цикла удалять из него элементы. Лучше составьте новый список, например:

```
import os

process_list = []

for current_process in os.popen("wmic process get name"):
    current_process = current_process.strip()
    if current_process not in process_list:
        process_list.append(current_process)

print(process_list)
```

В одну строку:

```
process_list = list({p.strip() for p in os.popen("wmic process get name")})
```

---

**PS.**

- `strip()` нужен для удаления пробелов и символов перевода на новую строку, например имя процесса `'wininit.exe                    \n'` станет `'wininit.exe'`

Answer (score 2):

Более легкий вариант для списков:

```py
lst = [1,2,4,8,6,4,3,8,9]

list(set(lst))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться швейцарским ножом- collections:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

items = [1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 1, 4]
print(list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(items).keys())) #[1, 2, 4, 3]
```

И по наводке @andreymal:

```
items = [1, 2, 2, 4, 3, 1, 4]
print(list(dict.fromkeys(items).keys())) #[1, 2, 4, 3]
```

Comment: Начиная с Python 3.7 словари упорядочены, так что вместо OrderedDict можно использовать обычный dict

Comment: @andreymal, не знал, спасибо